# lattice-tool path issue

Tags: perl

I have downloaded and installed a perl tool (lattice-tool).
But it is in my local directory.
While I'm running it says can't locate Directed.pm(a lib file) which is available in lib folder of my local directory.
I hope it will be set right if I set path variable. If so, how do I set it?

Answer (score 2):

For use lib you have to use full path, and you are should not use relativ path like this.

```
use '../lib';#not working in all times.
```

Scenario: Your scripts in something/bin/prog.pl, your lib is something/lib/lib.pm.

If you use relativ path, you should call your program like this:

```
cd something/bin/ && ./prog.pl
```

If you would like to use relativ path, use FindBin to find your current path:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";#your lib realitv to your script
use lib $FindBin::Bin;#your current script full path
```

Then you could call your program from anywhere it will always find its lib realtiv to itself.

```
cd ~   
something/bin/prog.pl# ti will use the correct lib
```

Answer (score 1):

In my scripts, I have the following (which I'm sure can be improved, but it has worked thus far):

```
my $mydir;  BEGIN { ($mydir) = ($0 =~ m#(.*)[/\\]#) or $mydir = '.'; }
use lib "$mydir/lib";
```

So the script tries to determine its own directory and then tells Perl to look for libraries within the `lib` subdirectory of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'lib' to the directories perl searches for modules.  You can do this with the `-I` flag:

```
 perl -Ilib lattice-tool.pl
```

Comment: Another option is to set the `$PERLLIB` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html):

```
use lib 'lib';
```

`lib` also checks for architecture specific sub directories under `lib` to make sure machine-dependent libraries are loaded.

**EDIT:** Note that directories passed to `lib` are relative to your current working directory, so that if you want to execute your script from another location you should use `use lib '/home/user1126070/lib'`.

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
The array @INC contains the list of places that the do EXPR , require, or use
constructs look for their library files. It initially consists of the arguments
to any -I command-line switches, followed by the default Perl library, probably
/usr/local/lib/perl, followed by ".", to represent the current directory. ("."
will not be appended if taint checks are enabled, either by -T or by -t .) If you
need to modify this at runtime, you should use the use lib pragma to get the
machine-dependent library properly loaded [...]
```